# equivalence of torchvision.transforms on Dart

Tags: flutter, model, torchvision

In my Python code, I used the `transforms` in `torchvision` to handle the input image before give it to my AI model.

```
from torchvision import transforms
loader = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(225),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
```

Now I want to move this AI model into Flutter app, which I need to do 2 things:

1. Convert the AI model to torchscript.
2. Convert the above preprocessing code to Dart language.

I have done the first, but how can I do the second thing? It seems there is no equivalence of `Transform` in Dart?